Java Time: plus days on UTC date/time changes the hour
Consider the following:
import java.time.*;
var today = Instant.now();
var futureDay1 = today.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusDays(1428826726);
var futureDay2 = today.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).plusDays(1428826726).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());

being ZoneId.systemDefault() the Europe/Rome timezone.
In the end, the following stands:
futureDay1 ==> +3914019-03-19T16:42:44.377406+01:00[Europe/Rome]
futureDay2 ==> +3914019-03-19T15:42:44.377406+01:00[Europe/Rome]

so, futureDay2 is one hour behind. I can't explain myself why. Current time (4 PM) is not at risk of DST, so why does it happen?
Of course, it does not happen for any number of days added.
And it's not just a problem of representation: if you convert both to milliseconds from Epoch, the two values are actually two distinct instants, so different long values.

You'll see this effect as your plusDays puts your system default zone to DST. Example: plusDays(1) gives same output, plusDays(180) shifts one value by 1hr

Hey guys, does it really make any difference that I'm adding a big or small number of days here? Come on!

No, that doesn't make any difference. What makes rhe difference is whether you end up in the standard time or the summer time part of the year. Java unreasonably expecting that the current summer time rules will be in effect forever. What else could it assume?

Simpler to check by hand: Summer time ends on 27 October this year 2024). So 26 Oct 12:00 UTC equals 14:00 in Italy. 27 Oct 12:00 equals 13:00. Which result would you expect from adding 1 day to 26 October in UTC? In Italian/Central European time?

@Anonymous what I would expect is that DST is irrelevant here, since the plusDays implementation passes through a LocalDateTime object. ZonedDateTime.plusDays Javadoc even says it explicitly. See my comment on the answer.

@Anonymous got it, see my last comment on accepted answer.

But it is a DST issue.
The date of the year you end up in has a DST change for the timezone you're using relative to the current date/date you ran this at, meaning that day is either longer or shorter than the same day in UTC. For any date after that (until the DST switches back) you're going to see this offset. It's irrelevant whether that DST change happens at 4 PM.

This. Rome has DST now, if you add 180 days instead of a bajillion the issue will also show up.

Sorry, I don't get it. Here I'm not adding a multiple of 24 hours, but I'm adding days. The Javadoc of ZonedDateTime even says that explicitly: "This operates on the local time-line, LocalDateTime#plusDays(long) adding days to the local date-time. This is then converted back to a ZonedDateTime, using the zone ID to obtain the offset.". OffsetDateTime implementation does the same. So, I wouldn't expect plusDays to change the hour due to DST, unless probably I'm in the 2-3 AM range of a day in which the DST occurs, due to convention (days +1 day means at 2 or 3?).

Ok, after trying with some intermediary steps I got it now. The problem is exactly that the hour remains the same, hence switching to/from UTC (which does not have DST) will result in a different hour change depending on whether the end date is on CEST or CET period. Thanks for help understanding this.

@MauroMolinari yeah, in other words the problem is that one of these '+1 days' actually adds 25 or 23 hours, because that's what it means in that timezone. 4 PM on 1 day means 4 PM on the next day if you add a day. Even if that means you need to add 23 or 25 hours.
